# How to combine env variables in k8s with variables in dockerfile?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Let's say I have a dockerfile:

```
...
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx1024m"
...
```

And I have a Helm chart for a deployment :

```
...
      containers:
        - name: "{{ $container.name }}"
          image: "{{ $container.image}}:{{ $container.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          env:
            - name: JAVA_OPTS
              value: "{{ $container.JAVA_OPTS }}"
...
```

How can I combine `JAVA_OPTS in the dockerfile` and `JAVA_OPTS in the helm chart?`

If `$container.JAVA_OPTS`  value is `-javaagent:my.jar`

The result should be
`JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx1024m -javaagent:my.jar"`

---

Add:
We have twro teams here, the JAVA developer may have their own `JAVA_OPTS` in the Dockerfile. And We(the ops team) want to add more `JAVA_OPTS`, (maybe combine them in the helm chart template). I'm looking for a technically solution.

Comment: Looking at the specific options, it seems like the `-javaagent:my.jar` line should be in the Dockerfile, maybe as part of the `CMD`, and you probably shouldn't specify `-Xms -Xmx` at all (the JVM can figure it out from the container resource limits).  Does that resolve the ambiguity?

Comment: Just an example, the JAVA developer may have their own JAVA_OPTS in the Dockerfile. and We(the ops team) want to add more JAVA_OPTS. I'm sorry I misled you by giving a bad example.

Answer (score 0):

environment variable set in the helm chart template (or pod manifest at the end) has higher priority than the environment variable defined in the Dockerfile.

You can combine both values by directly changing the templated value in your `values.yaml` like below:

```yaml
...
container:
  JAVA_OPTS: -javaagent:my.jar -Xms512m -Xmx1024m
...
```

Comment: Yes, I know. But we have are two teams here, the JAVA developer may have their own JAVA_OPTS in the Dockerfile. And We (the ops team) want to add more JAVA_OPTS. Is there a technically solution?

Comment: That is not possible by the design of how envs are set when launching containers. I suggest you keep defaults in the Dockerfile and make it configurable via the helm template. There is no such thing like devs do change Dockerfile and Ops do change Helm chart. Everybody should make changes to the central deployment artifact repo suggested by GitOps principles